# How to analysis and search within a minidump file

Tags: vb.net, dump

I've created a minidump file of a process. I'm trying t0 search within the process for specific values. For ease of use I've written the minidump to a file. Here's the ode that i'm trying to use to read the file:

```
Dim buffersss(13129250) As Char

Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\DUMPTHIS.MDMP")
    For i = 0 To 0
        Dim line As String
        sr.ReadBlock(buffersss, 13129220, 24).ToString()
        For j = 13129220 To 13129220 + 24
            line = line & buffersss(j)
        Next

        RichTextBox1.AppendText(line & Chr(13) & Chr(13))
    Next

End Using
```

The 13129220 is the location of a specific value I'm looking for (I've found this by using a some software). Ideally I want to be able to find the address of the value using the value (the opposite of what i'm currently trying). But at the moment this is the text I get in the richtextbox:

```
MDMP���a
```

Which makes no sense to me at all. I've tried getting other parts of the dump file and it just have the above repeated over and over. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look like an encoding issue. The constructor of `StreamReader` have an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which initializes a new instance with a specified character [encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\DUMPTHIS.MDMP", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
End Using
```